# Google API redirect URI other than localhost: how to make it the server domain

Tags: java, google-api, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, devops

I've been trying to set up an app with it talking to one of the Google APIs. When I deploy it to my linux server (shell only), it does ask me to go and "Please open the following address in your browser" with a redirect URI value of `localhost:some_port` .

I cannot access it from my linux machine and cannot open it on some other UI-based browser, since the redirect_uri is ALWAYS localhost based.

I've added my server public domain to the redirect URI list, but still it is always generated with localhost address.

**How can I get the token from the consent screen, since it always redirects me to localhost on my linux server?**

### Code

Code for creating connection (all fine on localhost, so no error here):

```
InputStream in = SearcherApplication.class.getResourceAsStream("/client_secret.json");
            GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets =
                    GoogleClientSecrets.load(jsonFactory, new InputStreamReader(in));
            GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow =
                    new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                            httpTransport, jsonFactory, clientSecrets, Collections.singleton(YOUTUBE_READONLY))
                            .setDataStoreFactory(dataStoreFactory)
                            .setAccessType("offline")
                            .build();
            return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(
                    flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
```

Comment: Show your code. In your code will be a section that specifies the redirect uri. You need to change that section of your code.

Comment: @JohnHanley I don't set the redirect URI programatically anywhere, just referring the client_secret json file. Edited post.

Comment: @JohnHanley I just recall there used to be a separate configuration on the console, where I was able to set the redirect URI by hand (not just the eligible URIs) - can't see it anywhere now.

Comment: If you look at the client secrests Json file, there will be `redirect_uris`. This is a list of URIs that you entered in the GCP console.

Comment: @JohnHanley yep, know that. Even if I list there my domain only (no localhost), it still is making me a localhost:portnum/Callback redirect URI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the place for that option. Instead of the `new LocalServerReceiver()` set the following code:
`new LocalServerReceiver.Builder()
                    .setHost("my.awesome.server")
                    .setPort(8080)
                    .setCallbackPath("/Callback")
                    .build()`